# itext pdf/a-3? setOutputIntents null Pointer?

Tags: java, scala, itext

I' trying to set the Conformance Level of my PDF's generated with iText (5.5.6, 5.5.7) to PDFConformance to A3-B

```
val writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, baos, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3B)
```

I'm doing that with:

```
val icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(profileData)
writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc)
```

Currently profileData is a Array[Byte] or an input stream which is filled with the data of `sRGB Color Space Profile.icm`.
I also use FontFactory.registerDirectory to register all my fonts and I'm setting the createXmpMetadata(), I'm using the XMLWorker to generate my PDF's via XHTML and a CSS file which specifies the fonts via * { font-family }

However I always get the following:

```
pdf-worker java.lang.NullPointerException: null
pdf-worker  at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:815) ~[itextpdf-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
pdf-worker  at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setOutputIntents(PdfWriter.java:1945) ~[itextpdf-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
pdf-worker  at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter.setOutputIntents(PdfAWriter.java:142) ~[itext-pdfa-5.5.6.jar:5.5.6]
pdf-worker  at de.envisia.pdf.worker.PdfService$$anonfun$generate$1.apply(PdfService.scala:45) ~[classes/:na]
pdf-worker  at de.envisia.pdf.worker.PdfService$$anonfun$generate$1.apply(PdfService.scala:30) ~[classes/:na]
pdf-worker  at com.twitter.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:13) ~[util-core_2.11-6.28.0.jar:6.28.0]
pdf-worker  at com.twitter.util.Future$.apply(Future.scala:99) ~[util-core_2.11-6.28.0.jar:6.28.0]
pdf-worker  at de.envisia.pdf.worker.PdfService.generate(PdfService.scala:30) ~[classes/:na]
pdf-worker  at de.envisia.pdf.worker.PdfService.render(PdfService.scala:24) ~[classes/:na]
pdf-worker  at de.envisia.pdf.worker.PdfController$$anonfun$6.apply(PdfController.scala:39) ~[classes/:na]
pdf-worker  at de.envisia.pdf.worker.PdfController$$anonfun$6.apply(PdfController.scala:38) ~[classes/:na]
```

I suspressed the rest of the stacktrace since it's stacktrace of finagle (my http server)

Could the error be that I'm using scala instead of Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An educated guess tells me that you're using `setOutputIntents()` at the wrong moment.

You probably have:

```
writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc)
document.open()
```

That's wrong, it should be:

```
document.open()
writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc)
```

When you `open()` the document, several objects in `PdfWriter` are being initialized. If you set the output intents before opening the document, those objects are still `null`.

Comment: yeah seems like that was the error since now I get another error:
`All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica` still I don't use Helvetica at all..
And if I resolve everything my Pdf only contains the items of the PageEvent and not my html content, strange.

Comment: Helvetica is the default font. Sometimes Helvetica is introduced without you knowing it (without explicitly defining it as a `Font`). Do you by any chance create a `Chunk`, `Phrase`, `Paragraph`,... without explicitly defining a font?

Comment: mostly I use XMLWorker and add a PageEvent and generate my Page Count with a PDFAStamper. The PageEvent only has a PdfTable which contains PdfCells with Paragraphas that has a Font and the Stamper uses ColumnText and Paragraph with Font.
The only thing is that my XMLWorker Content is missing if I embed Helvetica, but after inspecting the PDF Helvetica isn't there..

Comment: everything works now, I needed to set a FontProvider with CssAppliersImpl to my HtmPipelineContext, which makes now use of my Custom Fonts (Open Sans) Great!